# Is there a way to use external filters in ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I want to write a filter that is saved to a shared object or independent executable that can be used as any other ffmpeg filter.

I am using the architecture described here: http://nullprogram.com/blog/2017/07/02/ but it is not ideal as it is not integrated and I have to specify the framerate (even if I am not changing it) in the encoder after the filter has been aplied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a [frei0r](https://www.dyne.org/software/frei0r/) filter, which don't need to be linked at compile time, as long as the framework library has been linked.